# How to debug Karma when it fails

Tags: karma-runner

How can I debug a failing Karma test?

I am running mocha+chai+sinon tests without a problem. If I try to run the tests with Karma I get a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined" error and Karma stops running (I am using Webpack to transpile). The error seems to be with a Webpack loader, but the question is how to I debug this? As soon as I run the tests, karma fails and terminates.

How can I trace the karma execution?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure karma to stay alive in the background. Just add the option `singleRun: false` to your karma config. If you're using `grunt-karma`, you can also additionally set the `background: true` option.

If you then start karma, the window which opens up should stay open. There should be a `debug` link which will open a second window. This window will stay open and you'll be able to re-run all the tests by just pressing F5 / refresh. Inside that window you can debug the whole stuff using the dev tools (usually opened by pressing F12) of your choice.